# Speed up of the calculation of the sum the point-wise difference in R

Tags: r, matrix, euclidean-distance, computation, pairwise-distance

Suppose I have two datasets. The first one is:

```
t1<-sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
t2<-sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
t3<-sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
t4<-sample(11:20,10,replace = T)
t5<-sample(11:20,10,replace = T)
xtrain<-rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
xtrain
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
t1    7    3    9   10    4    9    2    1    6     9
t2    5    1    1    6    5    3   10    2    6     3
t3    8    6    9    7    9    2    3    5    1     8
t4   16   18   14   17   19   20   15   15   20    19
t5   13   14   18   13   11   19   13   17   16    14
```

The second one is:

```
t6<-sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
t7<-sample(11:20,10,replace = T)
xtest<-rbind(t6,t7)
xtest
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
t6    1    5    8    2   10    2    3    4    8     5
t7   14   18   15   12   17   20   17   13   16    17
```

What I did like to do is to calculate the sum of the distance between each row of `xtest` and each row of `xtrain`. For example:

```
sum((7-1)^2+(3-5)^2+(9-8)^2+.....(9-5)^2)
sum((5-1)^2+(1-5)^2+(1-8)^2+.....(4-5)^2)
...
sum((14-13)^2+(18-14)^2+(15-18)^2+.....(17-14)^2)
```

What I currently have is to use two for-loops (see below), which I don't think can handle large data sets:

```
sumPD<-function(vector1,vector2){
  sumPD1<-sum((vector1-vector2)^2)
  return(sumPD1)
}
loc<-matrix(NA,nrow=dim(xtrain)[1],ncol=dim(xtest)[1])
for(j in 1:dim(xtest)[1]){    
  for(i in 1:dim(xtrain)[1]){
     loc[i,j]<-sumPD(xtrain[i,],xtest[j,])
   }
 }
```

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to modify the code to make it efficient. Thank you in advance! Hope to have a good discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rdist` package has functions for quickly calculating these kinds of pairwise distances:

```
rdist::cdist(xtrain, xtest)^2
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   65 1029
[2,]   94 1324
[3,]  165 1103
[4,] 1189  213
[5,] 1271  191
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be `outer`

```
f1 <- Vectorize(function(i, j) sumPD(xtrain[i,], xtest[j,]))
loc2 <- outer(seq_len(nrow(xtrain)), seq_len(nrow(xtest)), f1)
identical(loc, loc2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could transpose your matrix, use vector difference and a single loop:

```
ftrain <- t(xtrain)
ftest <- t(xtest)


sapply(1:(dim(ftest)[2]),function(i){
  colSums((ftrain - ftest[,i])^2)
})


   [,1] [,2]
t1  103 1182
t2  125 1262
t3  130 1121
t4 1478  159
t5 1329  142
```

`colSums` is quite efficient, but have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774646/efficiency-of-matrix-rowsums-vs-colsums-in-r-vs-rcpp-vs-armadillo) if you want more speed

Comment: I think you can avoid the loop with `ntrain = nrow(xtrain); ntest = nrow(xtest);
matrix(rowSums( (xtrain[rep(1:ntrain, ntest), ] - xtest[rep(1:ntest, each=ntrain),])^2), nc=ntest)` although your way the intent is clearer

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple ways.

Using `dist` - will calculate more distances than needed:

```
dists <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(xtrain, xtest))^2)
dists <- dists[rownames(xtrain), rownames(xtest)]
dists
     t6   t7
t1  140 1179
t2  134  693
t3  119  974
t4 1028   91
t5 1085   44
```

Using a simple custom functions that works on X matrix and y vector:

```
euclid <- function(X,y) colSums((X-y)^2)
dists  <- mapply(euclid, list(t(xtrain)), split(xtest, row(xtest)))
dists
   [,1] [,2]
t1  140 1179
t2  134  693
t3  119  974
t4 1028   91
t5 1085   44
```