# Rcpp, Iterate DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp

I'm trying to realize a simple interop "R+Rcpp" and have strange problem with `DataFrame::iterator` and `std::algorithm` methods.

I have this code written on Rcpp.

```
struct TradeIndex
{
  Date date;
  
  long startIndex;
  long finishIndex;
  
  TradeIndex(Environment &tradeIndex)
  {
    date = Date(tradeIndex["Date"]);
    
    startIndex = Rcpp::as<long>(tradeIndex["StartIndex"]) - 1;
    finishIndex = Rcpp::as<long>(tradeIndex["FinishIndex"]) - 1;
  }
};

struct Asset
{
  std::string name;
  
  DataFrame ticks;
  std::vector<TradeIndex> indexes;
  
  DataFrame highQuantiles;
  DataFrame lowQuantiles;
  
  Asset(Environment &asset)
  {
     ticks = Rcpp::as<DataFrame>(asset["Ticks"]);
     indexes = std::vector<TradeIndex>();
      
     auto &&rawIndexes = Rcpp::as<List>(asset["Indexes"]);
     
     std::for_each(rawIndexes.begin(), rawIndexes.end(), [this](auto &&elem) 
     { 
        auto RElem = Rcpp::as<Environment>(elem);
        this->indexes.push_back(TradeIndex(RElem)); 
     });
      
     highQuantiles = Rcpp::as<DataFrame>(asset["HighQuantiles"]);
     lowQuantiles = Rcpp::as<DataFrame>(asset["LowQuantiles"]);
      
     name = Rcpp::as<std::string>(asset["Name"]);
  }
};


// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List StrategyRealization(Environment &RAsset, double basePortfolioMoney, double comission, Date startDate, Date endDate, 
                         std::string &open, std::string &stopLoss, std::string &takeProfit, int direction, double damperLvl)
{
  std::cout << "Started calculation" << std::endl;
  
  string directionString = direction == 1 ? "long" : "short";
  
  auto RAssetDataElem = Rcpp::as<Environment>(RAsset);
  auto asset = Asset(RAssetDataElem);
  
  auto &&quantiles = direction == 1 ? asset.lowQuantiles : asset.highQuantiles;
  
  auto &&quantileIterator = std::find_if(quantiles.begin(), quantiles.end(), [&startDate](DataFrame &&elem) 
  {
      DateVector &&dateVector = elem["Date"];
      return Date(dateVector[0]) == startDate; 
  });

  ...
}
```

Here `highQuantiles` and `lowQuantiles` are `DataFrames` with columns `Date, q1, q2, q3`,
where `Date` is a date vector, `q1, q2, q3` are numeric vectors.

But this code crashes.

If I write code like this

```
  auto &&quantileIterator = std::find_if(quantiles.begin(), quantiles.end(), [&startDate](auto &&elem) 
  {
      DateVector &&dateVector = elem["Date"];
      return Date(dateVector[0]) == startDate; 
  });
```

I get `<Rcpp::not_compatible in eval(ei, envir): Expecting a single value: [extent=813].>` error.

Please, could you explain me why?

Where can I read about iterators for `DataFrame`, `List`, `GenericVector`.

Comment: You could consider STL vectors (which Rcpp can convert to/from) as the Rcpp vectors have to strike a balance between being faithful to having an `SEXP` and providing some iterators.  And/or just use loops...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Correct me if I'm not right, but iteration with DataFrame::iterator goes through vectors a.k.a columns but not through dataframe rows, yes?

Comment: Yes because a `DataFrame` really is a list of (equal-length) vectors.  Each of those column objects is itself a vector you could iterate over 'vertically'.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I've understood my mistake. All this code doesn't correct

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Last question. Is it possible to iterate through matrix rows?

Comment: If you mean 'from left to right': no.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77078175 and it also follows from what we just discussed as DataFrame as a List of Vectors.